# Not getting proper redirect url(302) in location field of response header in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am working on one web-based application using JMeter tool. In application, after submitting my last request my URL is redirecting to one google link in which I am getting one access token which I need to be captured.

**Issues facing:** I am not getting correct URL in the location field of response header of the last request which I need to capture to proceed further.

Comment: Populating response fields is a responsibility of HTTP server. It is not quite clear what kind of help do you expect. The issue is described in very generic way.

Comment: We are doing API testing.For one API(in the middle) we need one token code which is generating in redirect URL of one web application flow .Since we are doing performance testing so I am adding the manual flow also in my script .The manual flow includes launch >Login>click on complete option>then after clicking it is showing success popup for 2 sec then page is redirecting to one google url which is having that access token code .I have done all the correlations and script for the flow but in my script the redirect URL in location field of response header is not coming correctly. I am getting